# AirFlow Measurement

Tags: measurements, airflow, experimental-physics, industrial-engineering

I'm a software developer, who wants to create a monitoring system for an industrial airflow system. The airflow of the system is huge - between 15 and 20 cubic liters per minute. Here is my problem, the strongest airflow sensor which could be connected to a microcomputer, is with capacity 300 SLPM which is 0.3 cubic liters per minute.

In summary I have the following questions:

1. Is there a way to use such a sensor to measure airflow which is much much bigger?
2. Maybe there is a way to decrease the airflow in a parallel connection where to put the sensor, measure it, than do some calculations in order to infer the real airflow?

Comment: Is the 300SLPM really 0.3 metres cubed per minute?

Comment: There is an error with your units of measurement, they should either be litres per minute or cubic metres per minute. You cannot have cubic litres. A litre is 1000 cubic centimetres, so it is already a cubic measurement.

Comment: I don't understand the claim hat you can't find a sensor for a high flowrate to connect to your computer. Flow sensors usually have a 4-20mA analog out (calibrated to flow range) and/or a gigital out (one impulse for a defined volume increment). What are you using?

Comment: I'm using Honeywell ZephyrTM Digital Airflow Sensor and their limit is 300 SLPM

Answer (score 1):

To measure an airflow you can measure the pressure drop across a section or before and after a bend.

That pressure difference can then be calculated into the flow rate.